# Combining data from an old table, into an exponentially bigger table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert data from table1 to an empty table2, but creating a row for each possible combination.
A simplified example:

This is table1

```
table1:
 firstname lastname
|Bob      |Jackson |
|Steve    |Smith   |
|John     |Walker  |
```

And i want to fill table2 accordingly:

```
table2:
 firstname lastname
|Bob      |Jackson |
|Bob      |Smith   |
|Bob      |Walker  |
|Steve    |Jackson |
|Steve    |Smith   |
|Steve    |Walker  |
|John     |Jackson |
|John     |Smith   |
|John     |Walker  |
```

Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Comment: read about `join` and `CREATE TABLE SELECT...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a pair of columns to cross all permutations between the two, you may use a simple `CROSS JOIN` joining the table to itself with a different alias.

```
SELECT
  -- Output columns come one each from the two different aliases
  t1.firstname,
  t2.lastname
FROM
  -- Use the same table on both sides of the join
  -- but with differing aliases t1, t2
  table1 t1
  CROSS JOIN table1 t2
ORDER BY t1.firstname, t2.lastname
```

[Here it is in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f2979d/4)

To apply that to a new table, use `CREATE TABLE AS...`

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT
  t1.firstname,
  t2.lastname
FROM
  table1 t1
  CROSS JOIN table1 t2
ORDER BY t1.firstname, t2.lastname
```

Note that it instead of `CROSS JOIN` (which is more correct) you could also do it with an `INNER JOIN` but omit the `ON` condition to match rows.  Either method produces a cartesian product of the two columns - all values of the first column multiplied by all values of the second column.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the Cartesian product

```
SELECT
b.firstname,
a.lastname
FROM Table1 a, Table1 b
```